# Java can't read one of data ResultSet for if statement, getter returns "0"

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have "users" and "reports" tables. There are 3 types of users, with "position_no" 0 (admin), 1 (manager), 2 (clerk).

Relations are correctly set.

I want to

- show reports with position_no 1 and 2 to admin.
- show reports with position_no 1 and 2 to manager.
- show reports with position_no 2 to clerk.

I already wrote codes for this. My problem is I couldn't detect which user is signed in. `rs.getString("position_no");` gives error: *"unreported exception SQLException"*, if I do try-catch, still same.

If I manually define new1 as 0, 1 or 2, it works correctly, but doesn't solve my problem. For example I defined for 0, if signed in user is 3, he will see as 0. I don't want this.

jframe window of the "see reports": [image: jframe window]

phpmyadmin table for users: [image: users table]

phpmyadmin table for reports: [image: reports table]

As alternative method, I added getter and setter to login_form.java then set to current user.

If I print getter in same file (loginform), it shows correct user position_no. If I set as 2 and print getter on other file like clerk.java, it prints "0" instead of 2. Why?

```
public void fillReportJTable(JTable table){       

    loginf.setUserTip(0);
  //System.out.println("Loginf value: " + loginf.getUserTip()); //getter shows 0 for all users
    //int new1 = loginf.getUserTip(); //temporary non-working solution with getter setter
    PreparedStatement st;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `position_no` = ?";

    //String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM `reports`";

    //if(rs.next()){ //it gives error. works without it.

    //this gets position no from db then goes to if statement 

    String tip = rs.getString("position_no");
    //System.out.println("new1 degeri: " + new1);
    int new1 = Integer.parseInt(tip);

    if(new1==0){
        selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM `reports`";
    }
    if(new1==1){
        selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM `reports` WHERE `position_no` = 1";
    }
    if(new1==2){
        selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM `reports` WHERE `position_no` = 2";
    }
    //}

    try {
        st= mcas.getConnection().prepareStatement(selectQuery);
        rs= st.executeQuery();

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();

        Object[] row;
        while(rs.next()){
            row = new Object[5];
            row[0] = rs.getInt(1); // productid
            row[1] = rs.getString(2); //product name
            row[2] = rs.getString(3); //report topic
            row[3] = rs.getString(4); //report text
            row[4] = rs.getString(5); //position_no

            tableModel.addRow(row);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CLIENT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

here is some code from login_form.java:

```
            String tip = rs.getString("position_no");

            System.out.println(tip);
            int new1 = Integer.parseInt(tip);

            Login_Form loginf = new Login_Form(); //welcome yazisi icin
            //int girisdegeri = new1;
            loginf.setUserTip(new1); //reports icin user tip
            System.out.println("Loginf degeri: " + loginf.getUserTip());
```

login_form top:

```
public class Login_Form extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private String publicusername; //username get set almak icin lazim
private int publicusertip; //user tipi alma see reports icin
```

Getter and setters in login_form:

```
public int getUserTip() {
return publicusertip;
}

public void setUserTip(int newName) {  // Usertip Setter    
this.publicusertip = newName;
}
```

Comment: As it stands, this code is going to throw a NullPointerException: `String tip = rs.getString("position_no");`.

Comment: You never execute the very first SQL with parameter. `rs` remains `null`.

Comment: You get that _"unreported exception SQLException"_ because you don't have a `throws` clause nor a try-catch for that exception... In any case, please reduce your code to a [mre]. With all the commented out code, weird alternatives, etc, it is hard to get a grip on what you're trying to do. Especially as your code seems to have problems (like NullPointerExceptions) which means it can't even do what you claim it is doing right now. We are not here to debug your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're defining a prepared statement with a parameter, but not actually setting that parameter. If you don't need to use the parameter then just use this as your first sql statement.

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
```

I'm also assuming there's some paraphrasing going on here,  because it doesn't look like you're actually getting a result set from your current or commented code. So maybe check that you're actually executing the statement, with or without a parameter.